# Get data from Node endpoint and pass into React frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, get

I am accessing a get request from a local node server and am receiving the databack into the React code but I don't know how to then use the received data. Complete beginner with React and Node.

```
const https = require("https");
const url =
"http://localhost:9001/products";
 https.get(url, res => {
    res.setEncoding("utf8");
    let body = ""
    res.on("data", data => {
        body += data;
    });
    res.on("end", () => {
      console.log(
          body
      );
    });
});
```

The console shows all the data being returned but now I want to use that data, pass it into a cost to be exported using

```
export default data;
```

whenever I try to alert the body outside of the cont url code, it says undefined. How to I grab the data to export?

Comment: May you please describe way you want to use data? I'd say, in your example data stored in the body variable, in callback scope only. Thus, your application doesn't see this data. Of course, better to save response in the redux state.

Comment: You can't export anything that is only created at runtime. Exports tell your module bundler where to find the code that it uses from other modules. You can't "transfer" runtime information with that. Probably this request belongs into some kind of `<Product>` components lifecycle methods. But I can't exactly tell as you didn't post any of your react code. Did you do the react/redux tutorial?

Comment: I currently have a data folder with a producst.js file and the products json hardcoded and a const called data which is exported. I want to pull the data from the node server instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect use case for a [Container Component](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0):

You should make the api call in a Parent/Container component and then store the response data in state. Then, you can pass the data down as props to any children:

```
const https = require("https");

export default class FetchData extends Component {

    constructor () {
        super();

        this.state = {
            data: null
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData();
    }

    fetchData = () => {
        const url = "http://localhost:9001/products";
        https.get(url, res => {
            res.setEncoding("utf8");
            let body = ""
            res.on("data", data => {
                body += data;
            });
            res.on("end", () => {
                // Store data to state
                this.setState({
                    data: body
                });
            });
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child1 data={this.state.data} />
                <Child2 data={this.state.data} />
                <Child3 data={this.state.data} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```